# Any reference for $ \Gamma(a) U(a,b,z) =\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{j+a} L^{b-1}_{j}(z) $

Tags: calculus, reference-request, special-functions, gamma-function, orthogonal-polynomials

Any reference that we can find the following $$ \Gamma(a) U(a,b,z) =\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{j+a} L^{b-1}_{j}(z),$$
where $\Gamma(.)$ is the Gamma's function, $U\left(a, b; z\right)$ is the Kummer's Function of the second kind and $L^{\alpha}_n(z)$ is the generalized Laguerre polinomials.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is formula (8) on page 28 of:  F.G. Tricomi, Fonctions hypergéométriques confluentes. Mémorial des sciences mathématiques, 140 (1960), p. 1-86. Availabe from http://www.numdam.org/item?id=MSM_1960__140__1_0

Answer (score 1):

1. [NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.1)
2. [Volume 1 of Higher Transcendental Functions](http://resolver.caltech.edu/CaltechAUTHORS:20140123-104529738)
3. [Wolfram Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConfluentHypergeometricFunctionoftheSecondKind.html)

Note that names of these functions have not been standardized so there can be some confusion. Kummer function of the second kind are also called Tricomi function or Gordon function. They do fall under the umbrella name of confluent hypergeometric functions of the second kind.

Comment: These are the definitions for $U$ or $\Psi$. I cannot find the formula. Not sure about Erdelyi [2],  6.12 (3 ff)

Comment: @ poweierstrass, what is the page number in Volume 1 of Higher Transcendental Functions ?

Comment: I was only pointing to resources for the functions in the equation. These may provide enough information to prove that the equation is correct.

Comment: In Volume 1 of Higher Transcendental Functions see Chapter 6 beginning on page 248. However, you should also see the section on notation starting on page 301.

Comment: The closest I could find is  Erdelyi vol. 1, 6.12 (3), as already noted by @gammatester. This is on page  275.